# Creating server for sending mail with multiple sending ip-s

Tags: email, postfix-mta

Im trying to build a server that will be able to send mail from multiple ip-s depending on sending domain.

> We are using Debian 8 with postfix 2.11.3 and ISPConfig 3.0.5.4.

How would i go and approach this problem? I have found some solutions like 
https://serverfault.com/questions/650057/postfix-multiple-ip-smtp-banner But i cant make it work.Keep getting this error and no mails will work

> fatal: bind 121.121.121.121 port 25: Address already in use

Can anyone who has managed to get it to work one way or another explain to me what must i do?

For example we have website named site.com and ip 121.121.121.121 ...how should my postfix configuration look for that site to use that ip ?

Ty in advance

Answer (score 0):

Hello again i have figured it out. This is how i got it to work in my configuration.

I will write here an example for domain test-domain.com and ip 121.121.121.121..

First add this line in main.cf

> sender_dependent_default_transport_maps =
> regexp:/etc/postfix/sdd_transport_maps.regexp

Then we create that file (sdd_transport_maps.regexp) in /etc/postfix
nano sdd_transport_maps.regexp

Inside that file we put following line

> /@test-domain.com$/ test-domain:

Finally we open /etc/postfix/master.cf and we place following lines at bottom

> test-domain  unix -       -        n       -       -       smtp
>
> -o smtp_bind_address=121.121.121.121
>
> -o smtp_helo_name= test-domain.com
>
> -o syslog_name=postfix-test-domain.com

Hope this will help someone.